# Get OS Version using API in service-now

Tags: powershell, operating-system, version, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm able to get server CLASS i.e [windows, linux etc] using Service Now API call as shown below marked with GREEN arrow.

I wish to retrive OS Version `7.9` as well from service now marked in RED arrow which I m unable to.

[image]

Powershell:

```
$osclass=C:\Temp\check_details.ps1 -SNuser snowuser -SNpass mysnowpass -ServerName MYSERVER1
Write-Host $osclass
```

C:\Temp\check_details.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'None')]
param
(
    [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $SNuser,

    [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $SNpass,
    
    [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $ServerName,
    [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $retobj = "sys_class_name"
)
# Build auth header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $SNuser, $SNpass)))
# Set proper headers
$HeaderAuth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $SNuser, $SNpass)))
$SNOWSessionHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$SNOWSessionHeader.Add('Authorization', ('Basic {0}' -f $HeaderAuth))
$SNOWSessionHeader.Add('Accept', 'application/json')
$Type = "application/json"

$srv = [uri]::EscapeDataString($ServerName)
$cmdburl = "https://mybank.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci?sysparm_query=name=" + $srv + "&subcategory=Computer"

$surl = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $cmdburl  -TimeoutSec 100 -Headers $SNOWSessionHeader -ContentType "application/json"

foreach ($result in $surl.result) {
    Write-Host "SNOW-OUTPUTYY:"
    Write-Host $result
}

$cmdburl = "https://mybank.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci?sysparm_query=name=" + $srv + "&subcategory=Computer&sysparm_fields=os_version"

Write-Host $cmdburl 

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $cmdburl  -TimeoutSec 100 -Headers $SNOWSessionHeader -ContentType "application/json"

# Check if the request was successful
if ($response.result) {
    # Iterate over the results and extract the OS version
    foreach ($result in $response.result) {
        $osVersion = $result.os_version
        Write-Host "SNOW-OUTPUTX:"
        Write-Host $osVersion
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Error: Failed to retrieve the OS version from the CMDB API."
}

$sretval = $surl.result.$retobj
return $sretval
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\meuser> $osclass=C:\Temp\check_details.ps1 -SNuser snowuser -SNpass mysnowpass -ServerName MYSERVER1
Write-Host $osclass
SNOW-OUTPUTYY:
@{attested_date=; skip_sync=false; operational_status=1; sys_updated_on=2024-03-14 07:41:31; attestation_score=; discovery_source=ServiceNow; first_discovered=2022-03-22 16:22:17; sys_updated_by=MIDServer.ASH.PROD; due_in=; sys_created_on=2022-03-22 16:22:17; sys_domain=; install_date=; gl_account=; invoice_number=; sys_created_by=MIDServer.User4; warranty_expiration=; u_business_function=; asset_tag=; fqdn=MYSERVER1.mgd.mrshmc.com; change_control=; owned_by=; checked_out=; sys_domain_path=/; 
business_unit=; u_escalation_support_group=; delivery_date=; maintenance_schedule=; install_status=1; cost_center=; attested_by=; supported_by=; dns_domain=mrshmc.com; name=MYSERVER1; assigned=; life_cycle_stage=; purchase_date=2019-04-26; subcategory=Computer; short_description=Web Server; assignment_group=; managed_by=; managed_by_group=; can_print=false; last_discovered=2024-03-14 07:41:31; sys_class_name=cmdb_ci_win_server; manufacturer=; sys_id=c00467039712c110a64cd124a253af71; po_number=; checked_in=; sys_class_path=/!!/!2/!(/!!/!#; life_cycle_stage_status=; mac_address=; vendor=; company=; justification=; model_number=; department=; x_nexsa_imc_nxt_last_seen=; assigned_to=; start_date=; x_nexsa_imc_nxt_platform=; comments=Pentaho; 
cost=; attestation_status=Not Yet Reviewed; sys_mod_count=100; u_assignment_group=; monitor=false; serial_number=7B5424C3-0099-4ACF-B4F9-4E75FD28E0BC; ip_address=10.14.28.78; model_id=; duplicate_of=; sys_tags=; cost_cc=USD; order_date=; schedule=; support_group=; environment=Test; due=; attested=false; correlation_id=0005fd9f-a494-ba27-32fa-b83fd26c27ee::7b5424c3-0099-4acf-b4f9-4e75fd28e0bc; unverified=false; attributes=; location=; asset=; category=Hardware; fault_count=0; lease_id=}
https://mybank.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci?sysparm_query=name=MYSERVER1&subcategory=Computer&sysparm_fields=os_version
SNOW-OUTPUTX:

cmdb_ci_win_server
```

As you can see i was wanting to see OS version 7.9 in the output `SNOW-OUTPUTX:` which does not print.

Can you please help?

Comment: The data you see is probably in another databse and the UI has a connection to visualize it for you. I would explore the SNOW database and its links so to figure out the best table to query, you can even end up with more than one api call to get the data.

Comment: The issue is with `$retobj`.. You don’t pass the parameter when you call the function so it takes the default…